# Match signs and parenthesis with regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, matching, parentheses

I've been working in .htaccess to make clean urls. Everything going perfect right now. Iv been able to make clean urls from all alfa-numeric characters with this regex `/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/`

I want to add now parenthesis `(` , `)`, `[`, `]` and the signs `&`, `%`, `;`  and I have no idea how...

After some work I came with this regex expression: `/([a-zA-Z0-9#%@()[]\-]+)/`.
But it does not seem to work,

I tried with regex tutorials and everything but I just don't get it.. If someone could help I will appreciate it

Comment: If you could explain what rewrite you are trying to achieve,provide some examples ... this may help: quite possible it can be solved differently without specifying all of these characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delimit special characters. The first closed bracket is probably closing the list.

Untested:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9#%@\(\)\[\]\-]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the reserved characters - inside of [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you need to escape `]`, `-`, `\` and `^`.

Your new regular expression would be: `/([a-zA-Z0-9#%@()[\]\-]+)/`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest version:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9#%&@;()[\]-]+)/
```